# Упростить код в php

Tags: php

Можно ли сделать этот код более маленьким:

```
'rowOptions'=>function($model){
    $dun="";
    if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-9 days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $dun='success';
    }
    if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-8 days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $dun='success';
    }
    if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-7 days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $dun='success';
    }
    if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-6 days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $dun='success';
    }
    if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-5 days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $dun='success';
    }
    if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-4 days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $dun='warning';
    }
    if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-3 days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $dun='warning';
    }
    if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-2 days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $dun='danger';
    }
    if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-1 days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $dun='danger';
    }
    if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-0 days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $dun='danger';
    }
    return [
        'class'=>$dun,
    ];
},
```

Comment: спасибо огромное я новичек просто

Comment: а что это вообще в принципе? там парень написал классный код  с помощью  switch Рекомендую ознакомиться!

Comment: @ДимаПерильман Он же ужасный. Зачем там цикл?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Используй сравнение дат, приведенных к одному виду (это работает)

```
'rowOptions'=>function($model){
    $dun = "success";

    if( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($model->data_okon. "-4 days")) <=  date("Y-m-d") ){
        $dun = 'warning';
    }

    if( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($model->data_okon. "-2 days")) <=  date("Y-m-d") ){
        $dun = 'danger';
    }

    return [
        'class' => $dun,
    ];
},
```

Если очень важно, чтобы $dun по умолчанию был пустым, добавь еще одно условие

Answer (score 5):

Одно из решений:

```
$sub = СравниваемаяДата - датаИзБазы;
if($sub < 9 && $sub >= 4){
    $dun='success';
}

if($sub < 4 && $sub >= 2){
    $dun='warning';
}

if($sub < 2){
    $dun='danger';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

И еще короче )

```
foreach ( [9 => 'success',4 => 'warning',2 => 'danger'] as $day => $action) 
    $dun = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($model->data_okon. "-{$day} days")) <= date('Y-m-d') ? $action : "";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
'rowOptions' => function($model) {
    $dun = "";
    for($i = 9; $i <= 0; $i--) {
        if(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($model->data_okon."-".$i." days")) == date("Y-m-d")) {
            switch($i) {
                case 9: case 8: case 7: case 6: case 5:
                    $dun = 'success'; break;
                case 4: case 3:
                    $dun = 'warning'; break;
                case 2: case 1: case 0:
                    $dun = 'danger'; break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }

    return ['class' => $dun];
},
```

Comment: код потерял свою функцию по раскраске данных в таблице(

Answer (score 3):

Ещё короче

```
'rowOptions'=>function($model){
    $dun="";
    for ($i=9; $i<=0; $i--){
        if(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($model->data_okon. "-".$i." days")) == date("Y-m-d"))
        {
            if ($i<=5) $dun = 'success';
            else if ($i<=3) $dun = 'warning';
            else $dun = 'danger';
            break;
        }
    }
    return [
        'class'=>$dun,
    ];
},
```