# отправить письмо php

Tags: php

как отправить письмо на почту в php, если почта указано в таблице human в столбце e_mail, но вот письмо должно отправляться по условию что у него заканчивается срок,
если есть такое условие

```
'rowOptions'=>function($model){
$dun = "success";

        if( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($model->data_okon. "-10 days")) <=  date("Y-m-d") ){
            $dun = 'warning';
        }
        if( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($model->data_okon. "-5 days")) <=  date("Y-m-d") ){
            $dun = 'danger';
        }
        return [
            'class' => $dun,
        ];
    },
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721338/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-php

Comment: Ну, получайте почту пользователя `$to`, делайте текст рыбу `$message` (или несколько), заголовок `$subject` (или несколько) и засовывайте `mail($to,$subject,$message);` в Ваши `if` кондиции

Answer (score 1):

Что-то по типу:

```
$to = ''; // засовываете сюда почту пользователя
$subj1 = 'Все хорошо';
$subj2 = 'Все не очень хорошо';  
$subj3 = 'Все совсем не хорошо';
$mess1 = 'На улице - солнце';
$mess2 = 'На улице - дождь';
$mess3 = 'На улице - ураган и маньяки';
'rowOptions'=>function($model){
    $dun = "success";

        if

( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($model->data_okon. "-10 days")) <=  date("Y-m-d") ){
            $dun = 'warning';
mail($to,$subj2,$mess2);
    }
    if( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($model->data_okon. "-5 days")) <=  date("Y-m-d") ){
        $dun = 'danger';
    }
    return [
        'class' => $dun,
mail($to,$subj3,$mess3);
    ];
},
```